# Send input in MDI form

Tags: dll, hook, mdi, navision

I am working on navision and i would like to add some kind of auto completion in it so i've created a dll that i injected into Navision and i was a able to capture the keystrokes. The thing is that when i tried to send an input to the application the children wouldn't respond to it. It uses an MDI form and i was sending the input into the father application thinking that he would handle the delivery of the message to the corrent child. I haven't used MDI forms before in my life so i would like some help as to what should i hook to deliver the input to the right child.

At the moment i am hooking TranslateMDISysAccel, GetMessage and CreateWindow and i've have tried to get the Handle of the child that i am intrested in from the CreateWindow and i was successful in that. After that i tried from both GetMessage and TranslateMDISysAccel to change the message that would be delivered with my parameters but it didn't work.
Any suggestions?

I can't post any code sample atm because i have cleaned up almost everything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a call to your dll from Nav's form field triggers like `OnInputChange()`?

Comment: Well i forgot to mention that i found out what was going wrong. I was trying to send a different input when a user was pressing the F9 key(i was send F5 aswell) but i wasn't modifying the the KeyCode and that's why it wasn't working. I am gonna try your suggestion aswell because it might be easier to implement.